# How to restart my Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser, silverlight-5.0

I need to restart completely my Silverlight 5 application, is there any way to do it, without having to reload the webpage ?

If the application is out-of-browser, I don't know how to do it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight 3 Out of Browser - Restart "application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251369/silverlight-3-out-of-browser-restart-application)

Comment: You can't force a restart. Ask the user to start the app again.

Comment: This hasn't changed since SL3, so, duplicate.